# Table row count throws an exception

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a table named backupfile, this is a copy of sys.backupfile that I am inserting into from all of the servers on in my network.

I was trying to see how big the table has gotten, and when I go to Properties - Storage it takes a while, and then I get this:

[image: table not looking right]

It has done this every time I have tried the last few days.

Could my data be corrupt?  We run dbcc checkdb weekly.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Yeah it's 21GB. Not sure why the row count error - does it happen every time? Only 112MB reported index space would suggest there's no indexes, creating a clustered index might solve it. Also you could try [DBCC UPDATEUSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-updateusage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Forrest ahh, yes, that does seem to be the case that it IS 21GB.

Comment: @GarethLyons there is a primary key on an int, otherwise no other indexes

Comment: Capturing SSMS (17.5) queries shows that it does a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`. What happens if you run that query against your table?

Comment: @GarethLyons updateusage has been running for 35 mins now and is still going